# selecting subclass for rollover not working?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a button with a rollover using jquery ui to add the class "ui-state-hover" so that the background color/color change on rollover.

Here is the css for the rollover:

```
.ui-state-hover { border: none; background: #d0e5f5 url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color:#fff !important; }
```

I am trying to add seperate css for a rollover on another button which has the class "ui-priority-cart" by adding this css:

```
.ui-priority-cart .ui-state-hover{color:#00dfff !important;}
```

however it does not seem to be affecting the color as it still remains white on rollover. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your button have both classes applied? Seeing a working demo would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS rule should be:

```
.ui-priority-cart.ui-state-hover { /* your rules here */ }
```

Note the lack of a space, this will apply to an element with **both** classes `ui-priority-cart` and `ui-state-hover`, which I believe is what you're looking for.

The difference is, the CSS you posted would apply to elements with a class of `ui-state-hover` *inside* an element with a class of `ui-priority-cart`.

Answer (score 0):

That applies to any element with the class `.ui-state-hover` that is a child of an element with a `.ui-priority-cart` class.

you may be looking for `.ui-priority-cart.ui-state-hover` which means any element that have both classes.